# Annotating in Django query based on a many to many relationship

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql

I am using Django with Postgres.

I have an object called Product and another called UserProfile. When a user likes a product, the product gets recorded in UserProfile's field like this:

```
watchedProducts = models.ManyToManyField('Product', related_name='user_where_watched', blank=True)
```

Now what I want to do is query the table of products and order products by the number of likes.

What I have (it's not working) is:

```
products = Product.objects.filter(fullSearchCondition).distinct().annotate(numOfLikes=RawSQL('SELECT COUNT(id) FROM "myapp_userprofile_watchedProducts" WHERE "product_id"=%s',(F('id'),))).order_by("numOfLikes")
```

The thing I am not getting is how to inject the product id into the query.

I also looked into Django's custom expression functions but it looks even more complicated to me.

Could somebody let me know a good way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You can annotate the queryset with:

```
from django.db.models import Count

products = Product.objects.filter(fullSearchCondition).annotate(
    numOfLikes=Count('user_where_watched')
).order_by('numOfLikes')
```

The only problem that can arise is that `fullSearchCondition` follows one-to-many or many-to-relations (other then to `'user_where_watched'`), and then thus retrieves the `Product` multiple times, but this will happen both with a raw query and a annotation, since the `.distinct()` requires *all* fields to be distinct, including the number of likes.

Comment: Hmm, I see, so would you say I should apply distinct() after the query somehow? What I am trying to achieve with distinct() is have just distinct ids, so the same Product is not returned twice by the query. This is because the fullSearchCondition includes things like searching by name, product owner, etc.

Comment: @Elendurwen: as long as you are only filtering on the direct fields of `Product`, or you follow `ForeignKey`s (on one direction) or `OneToOneField`s (in both directions), the same `Product` can not be returned twice. It is only when you filter on `ForeignKey`s in reverse, or `ManyToManyField`s, that the same record can be retrieved multiple times.